# Python tkinter growing call stack?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I'm making a program which calls a function to do some calculations, and there are buttons to press to change the inputs and recalculate.

It works great, except if a button is pressed before the calculations are finished, the new values are calculated and outputted before returning back to the previous values.  Basically, the program does what I want, except it returns to the first calculations after button press and completing second calculations (all the variable values return).

A general schematic of the problem:
1. Root mainloop
2. Values inputted
3. Press 'Go'
4. Calculations printed to screen (Monty Carlo sim by the way)
5. Press button to change input values
6. New calculations printed to screen
7. Once new ones finish, calculations for old variable values return until completion

Is there a way to prevent python from returning to the previous variable values like this?  My hope is that there is a way to return to the mainloop so that the calculations on the screen stay correct.  Thanks!

Edit:
Here's the code (Sorry it's a bit long and this is my first time with tkinter):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from random import *
from statistics import *
from math import *

'''
Prompt user for: number attacking with, number of defenders at each space
Output: n approaching 100000 and error range approaching .3%, probabilities of next roll, probabilities of winning at each spot, average number of pieces lost & stddev,buttons for decreasing defender/attacker

'''

def reset():
    attacker_entry.delete(0,END)
    for i in range(len(spaces_entry)):
        spaces_entry[i].delete(0,END)
    update_buttons()

def update_buttons(*args):
    buttons = [attacker_2,attacker_1,split_button,defender_1,defender_2]
    try:
        if int(attacker_entry.get()) > 1:
            for button in buttons:
                button['state'] = ['normal']
        elif int(attacker_entry.get()) == 1:
            attacker_2['state'] = ['disabled']
            split_button['state'] = ['disabled']
        elif int(attacker_entry.get()) == 0:
            for button in buttons:
                button['state'] = ['disabled']
            return
        if int(space1_entry.get()) > 1:
            defender_2['state'] = ['normal']
        elif int(space1_entry.get()) == 1:
            defender_2['state'] = ['disabled']
            split_button['state'] = ['disabled']
    except:
        for button in buttons:
            button['state'] = ['disabled']

def subtract(label,*args):
    if label == "both":
        label = "att def 1"
    end = int(label[-1:])
    if "att" in label:
        attacker_amount.set(int(attacker_entry.get()) - end)
    if "def" in label:
        space1.set(int(space1_entry.get()) - end)
    if int(space1_entry.get()) == 0:
        attacker_amount.set(int(attacker_entry.get()) - 1)
        for i in range(len(spaces)):
            try:
                spaces[i].set(int(spaces_entry[i+1].get()))
            except:
                spaces[i].set("")
                win_avgs[i].set("")
                pieces_left[i].set("")
                most_likely[i].set("")                
        space10.set("")
    update_buttons()
    go()

def check_if_multiple(list1,list2):
    if len(list1)>1 and len(list2)>1:
        ret_val = 2
    else:
        ret_val = 1
    return ret_val

def set_rolls(total,limit):
    list = []
    for i in range(total):
        if len(list) < limit:
            list.append(randrange(1,7))
    return list

def go(*args):
    update_buttons()
    try:
        attacker_total = int(attacker_entry.get())
    except:
        return

    defender_pieces_list = []
    for entry in spaces_entry:
        try:
            new_val = int(entry.get())
            if new_val == 0:
                None
            else:
                defender_pieces_list.append(new_val)
        except:
            None

    defender_total_spaces = len(defender_pieces_list)
    attacker_total_original = attacker_total

    total_trials = 10000
    defender_losses = 0
    attacker_losses = 0
    first_round_defender_total_wins = 0
    first_round_attacker_total_wins = 0
    first_round_split_total = 0

    space1_succ,space2_succ,space3_succ,space4_succ,space5_succ,space6_succ,space7_succ,space8_succ,space9_succ,space10_succ = [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]
    space1_all,space2_all,space3_all,space4_all,space5_all,space6_all,space7_all,space8_all,space9_all,space10_all = [],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[],[]

    succ_list = [space1_succ,space2_succ,space3_succ,space4_succ,space5_succ,space6_succ,space7_succ,space8_succ,space9_succ,space10_succ]
    all_list = [space1_all,space2_all,space3_all,space4_all,space5_all,space6_all,space7_all,space8_all,space9_all,space10_all]

    for trial in range(total_trials):
        if trial%20 == 0:
            for i in range(0,defender_total_spaces):
                try:
                    win_avgs[i].set(round(((len(succ_list[i]))/trial)*100,1))
                    pieces_left[i].set(str(round(mean(all_list[i]),2)))
                    most_likely[i].set(mode(all_list[i]))
                    root.update()
                except:
                    None
        attacker_total = attacker_total_original
        first_round = True
        for i in range(defender_total_spaces):
            defender_total = defender_pieces_list[i]
            while defender_total>0 and attacker_total > 0:
                defender_win = False
                attacker_win = False

                defender_rolls_list = set_rolls(defender_total,2)
                attacker_rolls_list = set_rolls(attacker_total,3)
                if len(attacker_rolls_list) == 1:
                    defender_rolls_list = [randrange(1,7)]

                for j in range(check_if_multiple(defender_rolls_list,attacker_rolls_list)):
                    if max(defender_rolls_list)>=max(attacker_rolls_list):
                        attacker_total += -1
                        defender_win = True
                    else:
                        defender_total += -1
                        attacker_win = True
                    attacker_rolls_list.remove(max(attacker_rolls_list))
                    defender_rolls_list.remove(max(defender_rolls_list))      

                if first_round == True:
                    if defender_win == True and attacker_win == True:
                        first_round_split_total += 1
                    elif attacker_win == True:
                        first_round_attacker_total_wins += 1
                    elif defender_win == True:
                        first_round_defender_total_wins += 1

                first_round = False

            if defender_total == 0:
                succ_list[i].append(attacker_total)
                all_list[i].append(attacker_total)
                if attacker_total == 1:
                    attacker_total == -1

            if attacker_total == 0:
                all_list[i].append(attacker_total)

            attacker_total += -1
    for i in range(0,defender_total_spaces):
        try:
            win_avgs[i].set(round(((len(succ_list[i]))/trial)*100,1))
            pieces_left[i].set(str(round(mean(all_list[i]),2))+"("+str(round(stdev(all_list[i]),1))+")")
            most_likely[i].set(mode(all_list[i]))
        except:
            None

height = 450
width = 600
shape = str(width) + "x" + str(height)

root = Tk()
root.title("Risk Probability Calculator")
root.geometry(shape)

content = ttk.Frame(root)
content.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
content.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
content.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

title = ttk.Label(content, text="Risk Probability Calculator", relief="ridge", background="gray",font=("TkHeadingFont",20),anchor="center")
title.grid(column=1, row=1, columnspan=8, padx=3, pady=4,sticky=(N,W,E,S))

reset_button = ttk.Button(content, text="Reset", command=reset)
reset_button.grid(column=1, row=2,padx=3, pady=4, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
go_button = ttk.Button(content, text="Go", command=go)
go_button.grid(column=2, row=2,padx=3, pady=4, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

ttk.Label(content, text="Attacking with:").grid(column=1, row=3,padx=3, pady=4, sticky=(NW))
ttk.Label(content, text="Defending with:").grid(column=1, row=4,padx=3, pady=4, sticky=(NW))
for i in range(5,15):
    text = "Space " + str(i-4) + ":"
    ttk.Label(content, text=text).grid(column=1,padx=3, pady=4, row=i, sticky=(N,E,S))

attacker_amount = StringVar()
attacker_entry = ttk.Entry(content, textvariable=attacker_amount, width=4)
attacker_entry.grid(column=2, row=3,padx=3, pady=4, sticky=(N, W, S))

spaces = []
spaces_entry = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    globals()['space'+str(i)] = StringVar()
    spaces.append(globals()['space'+str(i)])

    globals()['space'+str(i)+'_entry'] = ttk.Entry(content, textvariable=spaces[i-1], width=4)
    globals()['space'+str(i)+'_entry'].grid(column=2, row=(i+4),padx=3, pady=4, sticky=(N, W, S))
    spaces_entry.append(globals()['space'+str(i)+'_entry'])

attacker_2 = Button(content, text="Attacker -2",command=lambda: subtract("att 2"))
attacker_2.grid(column=4, row=2,padx=3, pady=4, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
attacker_1 = Button(content, text="Attacker -1",command=lambda: subtract("att 1"))
attacker_1.grid(column=5, row=2,padx=3, pady=4, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
split_button = Button(content, text="Split",command=lambda: subtract("both"))
split_button.grid(column=6, row=2,padx=3, pady=4, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
defender_1 = Button(content, text="Defender -1",command=lambda: subtract("def 1"))
defender_1.grid(column=7, row=2,padx=3, pady=4, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
defender_2 = Button(content, text="Defender -2",command=lambda: subtract("def 2"))
defender_2.grid(column=8, row=2,padx=3, pady=4, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

ttk.Separator(content,orient="vertical").grid(column=3,row=2,rowspan=15,padx=3, pady=4,sticky=(N,W,E,S))

results_frame = ttk.Labelframe(content, text='Results:')
results_frame.grid(column=4, row=3, columnspan=5, rowspan=12,padx=3, pady=4, sticky=(N,W,E,S))

pane = ttk.Panedwindow(results_frame, orient='horizontal')
pane.grid(column=1,row=1,columnspan=5,padx=3,sticky=(N,W,E,S))

pane1 = ttk.Labelframe(pane)
pane.add(pane1)
Label(pane1,text="% Win").grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=(N,W,E))

win_avgs = []
for i in range(1,11):
    globals()['win_avg'+str(i)] = StringVar()
    win_avgs.append(globals()['win_avg'+str(i)])
    Label(pane1,textvariable=win_avgs[i-1]).grid(column=1,row=i+1,padx=4, pady=4,sticky=(N,W,S))

pane2 = ttk.Labelframe(pane)
pane.add(pane2)
Label(pane2,text="Pieces Left").grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=(N,W,E))

pieces_left = []
for i in range(1,11):
    globals()['pieces_left'+str(i)] = StringVar()
    pieces_left.append(globals()['pieces_left'+str(i)])
    Label(pane2,textvariable=pieces_left[i-1]).grid(column=1,row=i+1,padx=4, pady=4,sticky=(N,W,S))

pane3 = ttk.Labelframe(pane)
pane.add(pane3)
Label(pane3,text="Most likely # of Pieces Left").grid(column=1,row=1,sticky=(N,W,E))

most_likely = []
for i in range(1,11):
    globals()['most_likely'+str(i)] = StringVar()
    most_likely.append(globals()['most_likely'+str(i)])
    Label(pane3,textvariable=most_likely[i-1]).grid(column=1,row=i+1,padx=4, pady=4,sticky=(N,W,S))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: could you post some relevant code?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is that it's because you call `root.update()`. This not only redraws the screen, but processes any pending events. A good rule of thumb is "never call `update`" for this exact reason. Infrequently you simply must, but usually there's a better way to organize your code. You can sometimes get away with it if you do it in a function that only takes a few ms, but it looks like your function computes a lot of things. If a user presses a key or clicks a button and then you call `update`, tkinter is going to try to process that event before continuing.

I would recommend first just removing the call and see what happens. If the screen seems to freeze (which it might, given how much code you're trying to run), you can try replacing it with `root.update_idletasks()`. That won't process any click or button events, only a certain class of event such as "repaint the screen".